# how to update the date?

Tags: python, django

when i'm updating the except all fields then updating well when i adding date field its not updating any data... plz let me know why....

forms.py

```
class EmployeeForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Employee
    fields = "__all__"
    widgets = {
        'edob': DateInput(), 'egender': forms.RadioSelect(),
    }
```

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
eid = models.CharField(max_length=20)
ename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
eemail = models.EmailField()
econtact = models.CharField(max_length=15)
esalary = models.CharField(max_length=100)
egender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=G_CHOICES, default='male')
edob = models.DateField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.ename

class Meta:
    db_table = "employee"
```

update.html

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Employee DOB:</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" name="edob" id="id_edob" required maxlength="15" value="{{ employee.edob }}" />
</div>
```

how to solve this didn't getting ....

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Employee DOB:</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" name="edob" id="id_edob" required maxlength="15" value="{{ Employee.edob }}" />
</div>
```

this should work...

Comment: u just changed E instead of e

Comment: here is my views.py def update(request, id):
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST, instance=employee)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("/show")
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {'employee': employee})